# How to detect first connection using express-session

Tags: node.js, express, session

It must be native, am I missing something ? I can set a counter bound to the request.session variable, although, I want a more explicit way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use express-session, it does not have a built-in way to know when the session is brand new.  A counter is a simple solution.  Or, this simple middleware implements the `isNew` property you asked about and avoids saving the session except the first two times it is accessed:

```
app.use(session(...));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (typeof req.session.isNew === "undefined") {
        req.session.isNew = true;
        req.session.save(next);
    } else if (req.session.isNew) {
        req.session.isNew = false;
        req.session.save(next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

// output value of isNew (only here for demonstration purposes)
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.session.isNew);
   next();
});
```

I should add that this also attempts to avoid race conditions by immediately saving the session (to the session store) as soon as it is updated so if two requests arrive close in time and the first one goes asynchronous allowing the second one to start, then the second one will still see the accurate value for `req.session.isNew`.

Answer (score 0):

```
req.session.isNew
```

session is always accessed through a request object, also there is a boolean field called isNew.

Edit: This is part of cookie-session which is a session middleware.

Comment: Can you find any documentation or code reference to this `.isNew` property?  I can find no code that references it in the [express-session code](https://github.com/expressjs/session) at all.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html

Comment: Part of cookie-session which is a middleware.

Comment: OK, just to be clear here.  `.isNew` is not part of default express-session implementation and I've shown that with a simple test app too.  So, if you want to use `.isNew`, you have to use the cookie-session middleware which is not part of express-session.  Is cookie-session compatible with express-session?  Or supposed to be a replacement for it?  The question was about express-session.

Comment: you are right, the question sought a solution whatever. The native solution from a starting technology I think is always better. You are right, I explained it is an addition middleware. I am waiting for a other solutions.

Comment: for your question, they explain the difference here: A user session can be stored in two main ways with cookies: on the server or on the client. This module stores the session data on the client within a cookie, while a module like express-session stores only a session identifier on the client within a cookie and stores the session data on the server, typically in a database.